# sum one column of a 2D array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make a program that will sum one column of a 2d array in java.

Me code so far is

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Excersiseone {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    double [][] array = new double [3][4];

    System.out.println("Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row by row :");
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length;row++){
    for (int coloumn = 0; coloumn < array[coloumn].length;coloumn++){
    array[row][coloumn] = input.nextDouble();
    //sumColumn(array,0);
    }
    }


}


 public static double sumColoumn(double[][] m  , coloumnIndex){
int sum = 0;
for(int j = 0; j <m[coloumnIndex].length; j++){
        sum += m[j][coloumnIndex];

    }

system.out.println(sum);
 }



 }
```

I get this error when I compile

C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\update\Excersiseone.java:22: error:  expected
double sumColoumn(double[][] m  , coloumnIndex){

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your method has to return a double, and you're returning nothing. Also you have to provide the data type for `coloumnIndex` (an `int` in this case). And `system` starts with an upper character (i.e : `System`)

Comment: Also `sumColoumn` is the method name, you try (when you remove the comment) to call `sumColumn` (without that `u`)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by ZouZou, if you only want to display the sum, then you should return void:

```
public static **void** displaySum(double[][] m  , coloumnIndex){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j <m[coloumnIndex].length; j++){
        sum += m[j][coloumnIndex];
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various compilations issues. Let me go through each one step by step.

1. As previously mentioned the method "sumColoumn" must return a double. If you just want to print the sum just use void:

   ```
   public static void displaySum(double[][] m, int coloumnIndex){
   ```
2. Also remember that all parameters must have a specified type. In the case of coloumnIndex you're missing the type. (See above)
3. Last but not least remember that the System class starts with a capital "S".